# ArrayAdapter - Ad every 10 articles works great, but takes the place of an article

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a list of articles, with an ad every 10 articles.  The problem is - instead of the ad being added to the list, it's actually taking the place of an article.

**Example of what's happening:**

```
- ad //taking the place of article 1
- article 2
- article 3
- article 4
...
- article 9
- article 10
- ad //taking the place of article 11
- article 12
```

The way I'm getting it to show an ad every X articles is this in my `ArrayAdapter`:

```
@Override
//determines which view type I want to use
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    this.currentLayout = position % 11 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    return this.currentLayout;
}

@Override
//says there are 2 different view types I want to use
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

So - I guess now that I see it happening, it makes sense WHY, but... how can I make the ad show up and THEN the next article?

**Previous Attempts:**

I previously had the article in my XML just below the article itself, then just toggled it on/off depending on the #, but was told that was excessive XML (and had some issues w/ it anyway).

I also tried adding the article as the next item whenever it was displaying an ad, but - were I not such a noob, I would have realized immediately that this doesn't work (it makes duplicates of the article - a LOT):

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //...
    if(this.currentLayout == 1) this.insert(this.getItem(position), position);
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make the ad show up and THEN the next article?

In your Adapter, you need to override `getCount()` to account for the ads, then adjust `position` in `getView()` to not load the wrong data.

In your example:

- `getCount()` should return in your example returns 12 articles + 2 ads = 14 rows.
- `getView()` should adjust `position` when you call `getItem()`, maybe: `getItem(position - (position / 11) + 1)` (But honestly I'm tired my maths could be way off.)

Comment: Is there documentation for getCount somewhere?  It's just empty here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getCount()  Mind giving me the general idea of what I'm supposed to do in getCount?  I don't know if it's just because I'm tired or a noob or both, but I can't wrap my head around what to do.

Comment: For ArrayAdapter, [`getCount()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.getCount%28%29) simply returns the size of the List that powers your ListView. This might work `public int getCount() { return super.getCount() * 1.1 + 1; }` That's 110% (rounded down) + 1, i.e. one ad for every ten articles plus a starting ad.

Comment: getting the total count is great, but how would I offset the `getItem(positon)` in the `getView`?  (thanks for your help thus far)

Comment: Post your `getView()` method in your question, at least the part where you assign the text.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge). It allows you to blend adapters and views into a single unified adapter and takes care of correcting the position for you.  You will probably have to create multiple instances of your `ArrayAdapter` to create sections and then place ads like there were section headings.